# UITableViewCell delegate indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Good time of day, I'm new in iOS development. I'm developing project where i have tableViewCell and button,progressBar on it. When i tap button indexPath of this cell is passed through delegate to viewController and then with another method i'm 
downloading some data and show it's progress in progressBar. So when i tap to one cell and then to another, progress in first cell stops and continues in second, could anyone help? Thanks in advance )
Here is delegate methods in viewController:

```
func didTouchButtonAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    songs[indexPath.row].isTapped = true
    let selectedSong = self.songs[indexPath.row] as Song
    DownloadManager.shared.delegate = self
    self.indexQueue.append(indexPath)
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    DownloadManager.shared.download(url: selectedSong.url , title: selectedSong.title)
}
func downloadProgress(_ progress: Progress) {        
    if (progress.completedUnitCount) < progress.totalUnitCount {
            selectedIndexPath = indexQueue.first
    }
    else if(!indexQueue.isEmpty){
        indexQueue.removeFirst()
    }
    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    print(progress.completedUnitCount, progress.totalUnitCount)
    print(indexQueue.count)
    var cell: ViewControllerTableViewCell?
    cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedIndexPath!) as? ViewControllerTableViewCell
    if cell != nil {
        cell?.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }
}
```

this is cell:

```
@IBAction func downloadButtonTouched(sender: Any){
    self.delegate?.didTouchButtonAt(self.indexPath!)
    self.progressBar.isHidden = false
}
```

As @RakshithNandish mentioned, I'v used list of indexPathes and when i tap to button, list adds indexPath. So, before passing progress to cell i check if progress is completed: if not, pass progress to first element of queue, otherwise just delete first element from queue, works fine.

Comment: `self.selectedIndexPath` get changed on your cell tap and `cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedIndexPath!) as? ViewControllerTableViewCell` is getting the tapped cell. so every time you select a cell it will show progress on that cell.

Comment: so how to solve this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to maintain a list of all cells on which the download has been initiated.. you could assign tags and each time a new cell is tapped for download, add that to your list and set the progress of each cell accordingly

Comment: @RakshithNandish thanks, i will try and give response

Comment: add cellforrowindexpath code..did u add tag to progressbar?

Comment: Using tags isn't preferred because tags are always integer which aren't self descriptive. Once a new developer who will be assigned with the project may run into problem because he won't have any idea about what tag is used for which view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model that may be an array which will hold the indexpath of tapped button's cell i.e. append indexpath to the array whenever button is tapped and remove it whenever you want. Later on while returning cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath you check if the array contains indexPath for which you are returning cell.

```
class DemoCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet button: UIButton!
}

class DemoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var buttonTappedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:       DemoCell.className, for: indexPath) as! DemoCell 
    if buttonTappedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
      //show progress view spinning or whatever you want
    } else {
      //don't show progress view
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: thanx for feedback but i've sold this problem and in tableview  there are visible only selected progressBars. What i want is when i tap to one cell and  then to another ones, progress must run in first selected cell, then next and so on. I've tried to use "queue" of indexes where i check if first cell's progress is completed then delete it, if not continue to pass progress to it.

Comment: @alikhanIf you have solved the problem, I suggest you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Iaxman could you show how to check if button isTapepd in cellForRowAtIndexPath ??

Comment: @laxmankhanal reputation is not enough, have to limit with words )